# Random freezes of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Could random freezes of Ubuntu 16.04 be related to an out-of-memory OOM spike?

I had similar problems and searching through the web I found this

https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom

My feedback is that I did not notice any freeze after installing `earlyoom`!

Comment: Add the link of this question, so please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191565/edit) your question